# The render class did not render the file at rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newbie with rails and here is my problem

I tried to write a very simple program with rails, and when I wrote an application.html.erb, it worked well.

Here is what I got

[image: Page when It worked well]

But, when I created a folder named "shared" and a file named _navbar.html.erb in that folder, I thought that I could render my code from that file navbar.html.erb to the file application.html.erb by this code

```
<body>
<%= render "shared/navbar" %>
<%= yield %>
</body>
```

The folder shared/_navbar.html.erb is in the folder views, which means it in the same folder with the folder layouts/application.html.erb

[image: My problem]

I am setting rails -v 7.0.4 and ruby -v 3.1.2

Here is all of my code, if you need

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/freelancer
```

Could you please give me some advices ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: The"_navbar.html.erb" file located in [app/views/shared](https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/freelancer/blob/main/app/views/shared/_navbar.html.erb) has no content?

Comment: @engineersmnky : I copied the content "Bulma, Home, Doc ... " from the file application.html.erb to the file _navbar.html.erb, that why I thought that I can render the file _navbar.html.erb by that code

Comment: Yes it would render if it were there. What I was pointing out is that at least in your repo there is no content so it renders nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the [Rails Guides about Layouts and Rendering](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#template-inheritance):

> This makes `app/views/application/` a great place for your shared partials, [...]

Following that advice from the official Rails guides, I would place the shared partial with the navigation into `app/views/appplication/_navbar.html.erb` and would call it from the layout view like this:

```
<%= render "navbar" %>
```

Alternatively, place the shared partial at `app/views/shared/_navbar.html.erb` and call it from the layout like this:

```
<%= render "shared/navbar" %>
```

Or, place the shared partial at `app/views/layouts/shared/_navbar.html.erb` and call it from the layout like this:

```
<%= render "layouts/shared/navbar" %>
```